# jQuery sort the DOM based on the numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

Following is the class which is repeated:

```
<div class="inner">
          <p> 
                    Text1 
                    <span class="plus"> 25</span>
                    <span class="minus">12</span>
          </p>
</div>



<div class="inner">
              <p> 
                        Text2 
                        <span class="plus"> 205</span>
                        <span class="minus">2</span>
              </p>
    </div>
```

I have two href tags to act as sort button:

```
<a href="#" id="pos">Sort by Positive.</a>
<a href="#" id="neg">Sort by Negative.</a>
```

Through jQuery, how can I re-render the dom, with the `<p>` sorted based on the button click?

**The fiddle is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pHyDm/2/).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$("#pos").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.inner').sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt($('.plus', a).text(), 10) - parseInt($('.plus', b).text(), 10);
  })
  .appendTo('div.main');
});

$("#neg").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.inner').sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt($('.minus', a).text(), 10) - parseInt($('.minus', b).text(), 10);
  })
  .appendTo('div.main');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pHyDm/8/

Though the two functions are basically the same and could/should probably be refactored a bit.